# How to use Frama-Clang to parse C++ programs

Tags: c++, frama-c

I have installed the plugin Frama-Clang of Frama-c to parse C++ programs. However, I don't know how to correctly use it. I tried it with a very simple c++ program but failed. 
Here is the code of test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I used the command frama-c test.cpp and got the following error:

```
[kernel] Parsing test.cpp (external front-end)
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/server3/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++/iostream:29:
/home/server3/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++/ostream:31:40: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
  class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<charT,traits> {
                                       ^
test.cpp:5:10: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' requested here
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
         ^
/home/server3/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++/iosfwd:37:68: note: template is declared here
  template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> > class basic_ios;
                                                                   ^
code generation aborted due to one compilation error
[kernel] User Error: Failed to parse C++ file. See Clang messages for more information
[kernel] User Error: stopping on file "test.cpp" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

Can someone tell me how to successfully parse it?

Comment: Any luck with this? I've been trying to do the same. I tried to give it include paths directly like this `frama-c -cpp-extra-args="-I /usr/include/c++/7.2.0 -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -I /usr/include/c++/7.2.0/backward -I /usr/local/include -I /usr/local/lib/clang/6.0.1/include -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I /usr/include" -cxx-c++stdlib-path="/usr/include/c++/7.2.0" hello.cpp` but it core dumps with no useful information.

Comment: @intheweeds no, it seems that  frama-clang doesn't support  the usage of STL.

Answer (score 4):

Your usage is correct: simply give it a `.cpp` file and it will try to parse it.

However, Hello World using `<iostream>` is not the best example due to the size and complexity of the STL: your program, after preprocessing, contains between 18k and 28k lines (depending on whether I use `g++` or `clang`).

As indicated in the Frama-Clang webpage,

> Frama-Clang is currently in an early stage of development. It is known to be incomplete (...)

Handling the STL is indeed one of the major difficulties in supporting C++, and currently under development.

If you try with a non-STL file, you should have better results. *Part* of the STL is supported, but there is no comprehensive list of which classes are and which aren't (as this is continually evolving).

For instance, the toy example below, which uses `std::exception`, templates and classes, is successfully parsed by Frama-Clang (despite a few warnings), simply by running `frama-c test.cpp`.

```
#include <exception>

class empty_stack: public std::exception {
  virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    return "stack is empty!";
  }
};

class full_stack: public std::exception {
  virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    return "stack is full!";
  }
};

template <class T>
class Stack {
private:
  T elems[10];
  unsigned index;
public:
  Stack() {
    index = 0;
  }
  void push(T const&);
  T pop();
  T top() const;
  bool empty() const {
    return index == 0;
  }
};

template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push (T const& elem) {
  if (index >= 10) throw new full_stack();
  elems[index++] = elem;
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop () {
  if (index == 0) throw new empty_stack;
  return elems[--index];
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::top () const {
  if (index == 0) throw new empty_stack;
  return elems[index-1];
}

int main() {
  try {
    Stack<int> intStack;
    intStack.push(7);
    intStack.push(42);
    return intStack.pop();
  } catch (char* ex) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```